# Database & Post Search

Tags: filters, database

Such as my site will include 10.000 posts with wp-category and 10 different taxonomies (age, country etc) and i can filter all posts by taxonomies and category. Which is better for database health?

1 - Creating custom post types for each categories such as Fashion CPT, Sport Cpt and filter by taxonomies.

2 - I use default wp posts for all posts with wp-category (fashion, sport etc) and filter by taxonomies...

Thanks

Comment: I don't see the difference between the two from a database standpoint, other than that 1 column in the posts table will have slightly different values

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference as far as database health. I would base the decision on whether "Post" is ideal for your case. Posts are best when you have time-sensitive content, such as news or blog posts, things that may be accurate when they're written but may fall out of date - as opposed to a CPT where typically you keep everything up to date. Posts have built-in RSS feeds, you can set WP to ping news services when you publish new ones, so if your content is slanted that way stick with Posts. If not, go with the CPT (which also makes it easier to add a blog later if you so desire).

Comment: Thanks for all commets. I really don' think ping services. Yes default wp post is better for me.